# Python - In a loop and want to check whether a condition exists (multiple columns) in the prior x rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looping through a DataFrame and want to check whether three conditions are met in the previous 150 records but not the last 30 or so.

The columns I'm wanting to check are TRAJ50_1, TRAJ100_1, TRAJ200_1 (where all have values less than 0)

I'm currently trying the following:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    if i > 0:

        if data.loc[i-150:i-30, (data['TRAJ50_1'][i] < 0) & (data['TRAJ100_1'] < 0) & (data['TRAJ200_1'] < 0)]:
            _recent_decline = 1
        else:
            _recent_decline = 0
```

This is resulting in the following error:

pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

I've spent hours searching but as a relative newbie to Python its a tad confusing.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
if data.loc[i-150:i-30, (data['TRAJ50_1'][i] < 0) & (data['TRAJ100_1'] < 0) & (data['TRAJ200_1'] < 0)]:
```

with:

```
if data.iloc[i-150:i-30][(data['TRAJ50_1'][i] < 0) & (data['TRAJ100_1'] < 0) & (data['TRAJ200_1'] < 0)]:
```

Comment: if data.iloc[i-150:i-30][(data['TRAJ50_1'][i] < 0) & (data['TRAJ100_1'][i] < 0) & (data['TRAJ200_1'][i] < 0)]:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: False

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```py
# s is True if all three columns are negative for the row
s = df[["TRAJ50_1", "TRAJ100_1", "TRAJ200_1"]].lt(0).all(axis=1)

# If there are any instances of s being True between 30 and 150 previous rows,
# set is_recent_decline to True
is_recent_decline = (s.rolling(150, closed="left").sum() - s.rolling(30, closed="left").sum()) > 0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. How does this know to only go back 150 records from the current position in the loop? I don't see any reference to current i

Comment: That's the beauty of `rolling(150, ...)`. There's no loop, it's *vectorized*

Comment: but I have lots of other checks in the loop comparing previous rows etc. I've heard of vectorizing for speed but its abit too advanced for me at the moment and would involve a lot of work to change the existing function. I will be looking at this once I've got the logic to work overall so thank you for pointing this solution out.

Comment: You should vectorize the other checks too. Using loops with pandas should be done as a last resort